# Why does my VBA script to format an Excel sheet is very slow?

Tags: vba, excel, format

I'm making an app in Excel-VBA, but when I have more than 50,000 records, code runs very slow, the formatting takes about 33 seconds.

```
Application.Interactive = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'--------------- Tao Bien ------------------------------------------
Dim Dulieu() As Variant
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim lastrowSC As Integer
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim NoDk, CoDk As Double
Dim PSNo As Double
Dim PSCo As Double
Dim NoCk As Double
Dim CoCk As Double
Dim TempArray() As Variant
Dim TheRange As Range
Dim Size As Integer
Dim TempArrayDao() As Variant
Dim lastrowTK As Integer
Dim TaiKhoan() As Variant
Dim FromDate As Date
Dim ToDate As Date


'--------------------Do Toc Do--------------------------------------
Dim Starttime As Double
Dim Code1 As Double
Dim Code2 As Double
Dim Code3 As Double
Dim Code4 As Double
Dim Code5 As Double
Dim Code6 As Double
Dim Code7 As Double
Starttime = Timer




'--------------- Xong Tao Bien --------------------------------------
NoDk = 0
CoDk = 0
PSNo = 0
PSCo = 0
NoCk = 0
CoCk = 0
lastrow = Sheet8.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row

'Them so du dau ky----------------------------------------------------

lastrowTK = Sheet7.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
TaiKhoan = Sheet7.Range("A2:H" & lastrowTK)


For i = LBound(TaiKhoan) To UBound(TaiKhoan)
    If Sheet26.Cells(4, 4).Text = TaiKhoan(i, 1) Then
        NoDk = TaiKhoan(i, 3)
        CoDk = TaiKhoan(i, 4)
        Sheet26.Cells(5, 3).Value = "Tên tài kho" & ChrW(7843) & "n : " & TaiKhoan(i, 2)
        Exit For
    End If

Next

Code1 = Round(Timer - Starttime, 2)
'----------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim NoCongDon As Double
Dim CoCongDon As Double

Sheet26.Select
' Dua Du lieu vao Array Dulieu
Dulieu = Sheet8.Range("G2:N" & lastrow).Value
FromDate = Sheet26.Cells(6, 3).Value
ToDate = Sheet26.Cells(7, 3).Value
Size = 1
ReDim TempArray(1 To 6, 1 To Size)
Dim tk As String
tk = Sheet26.Cells(4, 4).Text
For i = 1 To UBound(Dulieu)
    If ((StrComp(Left(tk, Len(Trim(tk))), Left(Dulieu(i, 6), Len(Trim(tk))), vbTextCompare) = 0) Or _
    (StrComp(Left(tk, Len(Trim(tk))), Left(Dulieu(i, 7), Len(Trim(tk))), vbTextCompare) = 0)) Then

        If (StrComp(Left(tk, Len(Trim(tk))), Left(Dulieu(i, 6), Len(Trim(tk))), vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
            If Dulieu(i, 3) < FromDate Then
            NoCongDon = NoCongDon + Dulieu(i, 8)
            ElseIf Dulieu(i, 3) = FromDate Or Dulieu(i, 3) <= ToDate Then
            TempArray(1, Size) = Dulieu(i, 1)
            TempArray(2, Size) = Dulieu(i, 3)
            TempArray(3, Size) = Dulieu(i, 5)
            TempArray(4, Size) = Dulieu(i, 7)
            TempArray(5, Size) = Dulieu(i, 8)
            Size = Size + 1
            ReDim Preserve TempArray(1 To 6, 1 To Size)
            End If
        Else
            If Dulieu(i, 3) < FromDate Then
            CoCongDon = CoCongDon + Dulieu(i, 8)
            ElseIf Dulieu(i, 3) = FromDate Or Dulieu(i, 3) <= ToDate Then
            TempArray(1, Size) = Dulieu(i, 1)
            TempArray(2, Size) = Dulieu(i, 3)
            TempArray(3, Size) = Dulieu(i, 5)
            TempArray(4, Size) = Dulieu(i, 6)
            TempArray(6, Size) = Dulieu(i, 8)
            Size = Size + 1
            ReDim Preserve TempArray(1 To 6, 1 To Size)
            End If
        End If


    End If
Next i

Code2 = Round(Timer - Starttime, 2)
'Dao lai Array Tam
ReDim TempArrayDao(1 To Size, 1 To 6)
For i = 1 To Size
    For j = 1 To 6
        TempArrayDao(i, j) = TempArray(j, i)
    Next
Next
k = UBound(TempArrayDao) + 14

'Add value to my sheet
Set TheRange = Sheet26.Range("A15:F" & k)
TheRange.Value = TempArrayDao
```

Format my sheet, is take me 33s to format my sheet, i don't know why  ..

```
With Sheet26
    With .Range("A14:F" & k + 1)
        .ClearFormats
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
     End With
Code4 = Round(Timer - Starttime, 2) ' code4 is 0.4 s
    With .Range("C14:C" & k)
        .WrapText = True
        .Rows.AutoFit
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With

Code5 = Round(Timer - Starttime, 2) 'code5 is 13,14s
    .Range("A14:B" & k).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Range("A14:B" & k).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter

    With .Range("D14:D" & k)
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .NumberFormat = "@"
    End With

    With .Range("E14:F" & k + 1)
        .NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);_(* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter

    End With
    .Range("C" & k & ":C" & k + 1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Range("B14:B" & k).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

Code6 = Round(Timer - Starttime, 2) ' code6 is 33,97 s
End With


With Sheet26.Range("A" & k & ":F" & k + 1)
    .Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark2
    .Font.Bold = True
End With
ReDim Dulieu(0, 0) As Variant
ReDim TempArray(0, 0) As Variant
Set TheRange = Nothing
ReDim TempArrayDao(0, 0) As Variant
ReDim TaiKhoan(0, 0) As Variant
Application.Interactive = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: If you can expand on exactly what this code is supposed to be doing, and include enough context (where did `TempArrayDao` come from?) - heck, include the whole procedure, speeding up slow but otherwise working code is best asked on [codereview.se].

Comment: If you provide the info that Mat mentioned, on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) make sure to include sample data - your code on my machine (50,000 rows of integers) took 0.9 seconds; my changes 0.2 seconds, but I think the main issue is your data

Comment: Thanks for help, i edited my post, is that something incorrect ?

Comment: Using the `Text` property of a range gets very slow. Use `Value2` if you can.

Comment: Thanks @Rory, but it still slow :(

Comment: What sort of data is stored in your sheet? If you have any volatile functions, this could have a big impact. You could try adding `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` at the beginning and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` at the end

Comment: you could also try to freeze the screen while the code is running by adding `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the start and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end. This has worked for me in the past when I am trying to format a screen. @TrươngNgọcĐăngKhoa